# Do Scala worksheet (or REPL logs) belong to the SCM?

Tags: testing, scala, ide, scm

The Eclipse Scala IDE (and Intellij Idea, too) has, together with a standard REPL CLI, an artifact named [Worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started), that works like a persistent REPL log: the whole file is compiled and executed at save time, and the results are in-lined as comments. It is a great tool for API exploration and design, and initial testing.

Is there any guideline if such a file belongs to the SCM?

I usually don't share those files, because they are often rough, limited in scope and not commented, being a way to test and try different ideas. Sometimes, however, a worksheet gains enough value and informative content to become valuable.

Should it be converted to a unit test or committed as is? do you find it an effective way to document and share the design or some example usage of a piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if it's valuable enough to be used repeatedly over a period of more than a few days, either by running it or simply by reading it, and particularly if more than one person would use it, then yes it does belong in the SCM.

This should make it easy to find find for everyone working on the project, and allow it to be updated alongside the code which it tests.

In *Continuous Delivery*, Jez Humble and David Farley recommend keeping all parts of the project together in version control, including source code, documentation etc (but generally not compiled binaries).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. They are source files after all.

You ask about whether you should convert them into tests but in a sense they already are tests. Anyone becoming familiar with the project may well find them useful examples of how it works.

There are cases where you might want to have worksheets that acts as scratch pads but that you don't want to put the project's repository because they depends on things that are local to your development environment. But it could still be a good idea to put them in soms repository, especially if you intend to use them more than once.